# Quickened spells and concentration

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic, concentration

I understand that I can't *cast* two spells per round (PHB p.202) even when using the Quickened Spell metamagic feat. However, is it allowable to cast a concentration spell like Crown of Madness on one turn, then on the following turn to use my main action to maintain that spell, and use Quickened Spell to cast another (non-concentration) spell with my bonus action?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se, I see you've already taken the tour :) - As a suggestion, I would rethink the title of the question. It's more about using an action to maintain a spell than concentration itself. For example, Invisibility is a completely different concentration spell that doesn't share the same answer (as casting a spell in your next turn makes the spell end and it doesn't need an action to maintain it). Also, there's no need to state the game system or edition in the title - it's already tagged as dnd-5e, so we know it's about D&D 5e.

Comment: (My comment was too large, sorry) Part 2: Also, it's not exactly about Quickened Spells - it's about casting spells as a Bonus Action (the method doesn't matter). Although Sorcerer doesn't have many spells that use Bonus Action as casting time, Expeditious Retreat is a simple example that applies.
A possible title would be something like "Can I use an action to maintain a spell and cast another spell as a bonus action?". I'm not editing it myself because I'm not completely sure I understood your intentions behind the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, you can do it

Maintaining the spell is not casting it.

> On your subsequent turns, you must use your action to maintain control over the target, or the spell ends. Also, the target can make a Wisdom saving throw at the end of each of its turns. On a success, the spell ends.

Note that it says "use your action to maintain control over the target" - that's not casting a spell. If it was worded like "you must use your action to cast this spell again, without using spell slots", for example, you wouldn't be able to cast another spell as a bonus action in the same turn.

One simple way to see that you are not casting the spell again is that you don't expend any additional spell slots, even though the spell you would be casting is not a cantrip and it doesn't state you don't spend a spell slot (i.e. there is no specific rule in the spell telling you to go against the general rule - which would be to spend a spell slot).

As a note, the fact that it is a concentration spell doesn't matter. The only thing this changes is that the spell you are casting in the next round/turn must be non-concentration, as mentioned by you.

---

## Side note

> I understand that I can't cast two spells per round (PHB p.202) [...]

This is wrong.

You are not allowed to cast a spell as bonus action and then another (non-cantrip) spell as an action. (For clarification, you can't do it the other way around either, i.e., you can't cast a (non-cantrip) spell as an action and then cast another as a bonus action. For curiosity, you can't cast a (non-cantrip) spell as an action and a cantrip as a bonus action either. The cantrip has to be the action.)

You can, however, use more than one spell in your turn. For example, you can cast one spell as an action and another as a reaction, or use Action Surge (either multicass into fighter or EK) and use two spells as actions in the same turn. (Trivially, you can combine both the things I mentioned and cast *three* spells in a turn)

Comment: I would clarify your side note to also indicate that you can't go in the other order either, casting a spell with your action and then with your bonus action as well.

Comment: @kamildrakari you actually can cast an action cantrip and then a bonus action spell, nothing disallows for this.

Comment: @Medix2 see, I knew just saying "a spell" instead of "a non-cantrip spell" would come back to bite me...

Comment: @KamilDrakari added that clarification. Also added a random curiosity about that ruling as well. (I call it curiosity because there are few bonus action cantrips, and you usually don't want to cast a spell with them.)

Answer (score 2):

We need to break this down a bit.

> I understand that I can't cast two spells per round (PHB p.202) even when using the Quickened Spell metamagic feature.

You can't consume two *spell slots* in a single round, but there's nothing stopping you from casting a spell as an action or bonus action, and then casting a *cantrip* as a, respectively, bonus action or action. So long as one is a cantrip, the other can be whatever.

> cast a concentration spell like Crown of Madness on one turn, then on the following turn to use my main action to maintain that spell, and use Quickened Spell to cast another (non-concentration) spell with my bonus action?

Concentration spells don't require an action to maintain unless stated otherwise. They only require that you not cast another spell that requires concentration, and that you not encounter an effect which breaks concentration (usually damage). So if you cast another spell the next turn, regardless of whether it takes an action or a bonus action, the only stipulation is that it not require concentration. If it doesn't, then you're free to cast the spell *and* maintain concentration on your previous spell.

Spells which specifically require you to spend an action to maintain concentration have that precise condition: spend an action maintaining the spell, and the spell's duration is maintained. Performing a bonus action on top of that, so long as the bonus-action spell doesn't require concentration, won't break the original spell's concentration.

Comment: Concentration spells don't require an action to maintain, but some spells (which are concentrations spells) do, such as Crown of Madness. I could have worded that better, but my question still stands.

Comment: might also want to add in action surge allows 2 spells in one round

Comment: Even if your Bonus Action spell is a cantrip, you can only cast a cantrip with your Action if you cast any spell with a Bonus Action.

Comment: What GreySage said. [The rule](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) doesn't talk about multiple leveled spells per turn; it says that if you cast a spell as a bonus action, "You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action." This means that if you cast anything as a bonus action, even a cantrip, you can't cast any new spell on the same turn except a cantrip. (Maintaining concentration on a previously cast spell doesn't violate this rule.)

Comment: "You can't consume two spell slots in a single round" -> Wrong. You could cast one spell with your action, cast  a reaction spell like Shield if your movement provoked an opportunity attack and cast a third with Action Surge. That's three spell slots used in one turn.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm always a bit confused about that rule, can I use Action to cast spell then use Bonus Action to cast another spell?

Comment: @Vylix: Nope. If you cast a spell as a bonus action, you can not cast another non-cantrip spell that turn (either before or after the bonus-action spell).